# Reading single columns from tab delimited text file

Tags: c++, qt

here an example (a part) of the tab delimited file from which I want to extract columns for separated elaborations:

```
 0.0000000000000000e+000     -2.2562500000000000e+001    -2.0625000074505806e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001    -3.0625000223517418e-001   
  9.9999999392252903e-009    -2.5687500000000000e+001    -2.0625000074505806e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001    -3.0625000223517418e-001   
  1.9999999878450581e-008    -3.1937500000000000e+001    -3.6250000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -3.0625000223517418e-001   
  2.9999999817675871e-008    -3.3500000000000000e+001    -3.6250000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -3.0625000223517418e-001   
  3.9999999756901161e-008    -3.1937500000000000e+001    -2.0625000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  4.9999999696126451e-008    -3.0375000000000000e+001     1.0624999925494194e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002     1.6249999776482582e-001   
  5.9999999635351742e-008    -2.4125000000000000e+001     1.0624999925494194e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  6.9999999574577032e-008    -1.9437500000000000e+001     1.0624999925494194e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  7.9999999513802322e-008    -1.9437500000000000e+001     1.0624999925494194e-001    -2.5625000149011612e-001    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  8.9999999453027613e-008    -1.9437500000000000e+001     2.6249999925494194e-001    -2.5625000149011612e-001     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  9.9999999392252903e-008    -1.1625000000000000e+001     2.6249999925494194e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001     1.6249999776482582e-001   
  1.0999999933147819e-007     4.0000000000000000e+000     2.6249999925494194e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001     1.6249999776482582e-001   
  1.1999999927070348e-007     1.1812500000000000e+001     1.0624999925494194e-001    -1.0000000149011612e-001     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  1.2999999920992877e-007     8.6875000000000000e+000     1.0624999925494194e-001    -2.5625000149011612e-001    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  1.3999999914915406e-007     8.6875000000000000e+000    -5.0000000745058060e-002     5.6249998509883881e-002     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  1.4999999908837935e-007     1.3375000000000000e+001    -5.0000000745058060e-002    -1.0000000149011612e-001    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  1.5999999902760464e-007     1.1812500000000000e+001    -5.0000000745058060e-002    -1.0000000149011612e-001    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  1.6999999896682993e-007     8.6875000000000000e+000    -2.0625000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -1.5000000223517418e-001   
  1.7999999890605523e-007     8.6875000000000000e+000    -2.0625000074505806e-001     2.1249999850988388e-001     6.2499977648258209e-003   
  1.8999999884528052e-007     1.3375000000000000e+001    -3.6250000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -3.0625000223517418e-001   
  1.9999999878450581e-007     8.6875000000000000e+000    -3.6250000074505806e-001     5.6249998509883881e-002    -3.0625000223517418e-001
```

from this data, I want to extract for example the second and the fourth columns. 
What is a simple way (code) to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

This is the part to open the file (qt framework):

```
void MainWindow::on_Button_FirstColumn_clicked()
{
    QFile dataAG("C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/Segmentazione+GUI_GFAC/20130909_LT25A_E21_H20_1/data_t_U_I_test.txt");
    if(dataAG.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {


    QTextStream stream(&dataAG);
    //QString line;
    ui->textBrowser->setText(stream.readAll());

    dataAG.close();
}

}
```

this is the code to read columns:

```
void MainWindow::on_LoadVoltageButton_clicked()
{   
    float  col1[74],col2[74],col3[74],col4[74],col5[74];
    int num=0;
    string Load;
    ifstream dataAgie;
    dataAgie.open("C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/Segmentazione+GUI_GFAC/20130909_LT25A_E21_H20_1/data_t_U_I_test.txt");
    if(dataAgie.fail()) // checks to see if file opended 
    { 
      QMessageBox::information(this,tr("STOP"),tr("Error with loading"));
      //this->close();
      } 
    while(getline(dataAgie,Load)) // reads file to end of *file*, not line
      {  
         istringstream is(Load);
         double P;
         double Q;
         int n=0;
         is >> P >> Q;

      } 

}
```

Comment: Have you already tried some approach? Please show some effort on solving your problem and return if you are stuck at a specific point.

Comment: I think that the best thing is to parse the file and create a 2d array with float/double values and then access your columns by indexing into your 2d array.

Comment: @anderas Yes...I tried severals approaches, with the last I have some problems to recognize the "dot" before the decimal numbers.

Comment: @Simon This is a possibility....but consider that my fyle is very huge: 200 Mb with milions of records.

Comment: "I tried severals approaches" . Post the code of the best try.

Comment: @CecchinoSMI so show a (minimal) example of your last effort and tell what is going wrong exactly. What do you expect and what do you see? Otherwise, we are not (really) able to help you.

Comment: A couple of questions: Do you know beforehand which columns you will need to read? Do you know beforehand how many columns are in your data file? Also, re you sure that you can't hold 200Mb in memory?

Comment: @Simon The columns to read change by porpuses, but above there is an example of the .txt file. About the size of the file 200 Mb its ok!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<float> column1;
vector<float> column2;
vector<float> column3;
float temp1;
float temp2;
float temp3;

ifstream file("numbers");

while ((file >> temp1) && (file >> temp2) && (file >> temp3))
{
  column1.push_back(temp1);
  column2.push_back(temp2);
  column3.push_back(temp3);
}
```

Not the fastest solution but short and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Using the column iterator I made [here](http://ideone.com/nFH4Xf) you can simply do this:

```c++
int main() {
    auto c2 = read_columns<double>(is, 2);
    auto c4 = read_columns<double>(is, 4)
}
```

You can even hold the columns in a map for easy access:

```c++
std::map<int, std::vector<double>> columns;

columns.emplace(std::make_pair(2, c2));
columns.emplace(std::make_pair(4, c4));
```